# SBT, Jetty and Servlet 3.0

Tags: servlets, jetty, sbt

I have a really tiny problem.

I have the following build.sbt file:

```
name := "Tueet"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.2.v20120308"
```

After invoking sbt update, I get the following:

```
[info] Set current project to Tueet (in build file:/C:/dev/tueet/)
[info] Updating {file:/C:/dev/tueet/}default-d5e982...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.9.1 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-webapp;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-xml;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-util;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-servlet;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-security;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-server;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-continuation;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-http;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[info] Resolving org.eclipse.jetty#jetty-io;8.1.2.v20120308 ...
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit (603ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/C:/dev/tueet/}default-d5e982/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download     failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 2012-03-27 14:33:34
```

This is silly, as it works in Maven no prob. I found out that this is because Orbit does something with packaging (they set it to orbit apparently).

I tried doing exclude("org.eclipse.jetty.orbit", "javax.servlet") but nothing happened and it still needed that dependency.

I couldn't find any info on how to actually fix this, maybe someone will help me here :)

**Update:** the presented bug provides a workaround, so to fix this problem I actually changed build.sbt to

```
name := "Tueet"

libraryDependencies += "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % "8.1.2.v20120308"

ivyXML := 
<dependency org="org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" name="javax.servlet" rev="3.0.0.v201112011016">
<artifact name="javax.servlet" type="orbit" ext="jar"/>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In case the fix doesn't help you should try clear ivy caches fot jetty.

Comment: I am unable to get it working even with the inlined `ivyXML` fix

Comment: Thanks @tonek! This worked: rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this bug: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-1493

The crux of the issue is that ivy doesn't support the orbit extension and needs to map the orbit packaging type to jar.  Not sure if you're using ivy or not there, but the fundamental reason is the same, you can see that by looking at the url it is downloading from maven central.

This bug has a bit more of the background on the reason we switched to these dependencies in the first place.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371954

Comment: In practice what happens is that ivy users are rolling back to an older version of Jetty: https://github.com/robfletcher/betamax/issues/63 (this is also what we are doing).

Comment: It has been a while, I'll take a look at the issue again and see if we can sort out a better solution.  Eclipse is looking at getting orbit itself into a more maven friendly form which would be great but it is unclear when that is going to happen and when that might make it to maven central.  Personally I wise we could just depend on normal artifacts but alas that is not allowed by Eclipse Foundation IP policy.

Comment: I stand corrected: upgrading to Gradle 1.4 also fixes the problem, and Orbit dependencies work out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 6):

I found a workaround. Further information can be found here: [SBT, Jetty and Servlet 3.0](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/issues/499).

```
classpathTypes ~= (_ + "orbit")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container"         artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
  )
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.4.v20120524" % "container" artifacts            (Artifact("jetty-webapp", "jar", "jar"))
)
```

Comment: you dont need to override artifacts for jetty-webapp

Answer (score 1):

with sbt 0.12+ (from:https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/499)

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container" artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
)
```