# create JAR for Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, sbt, distributed-computing

I am following this [guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/quick-start.html), but I cannot run Scala in Spark, when I am trying to create the JAR with *sbt*.

I have *simple.sbt* as:

```
name := "Simple Project"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0"
```

Here is the error:

```
sbt package
[INFO]  ..
[warn]  [NOT FOUND  ] org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit (255ms)
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/javax.servlet-3.0.0.v201112011016.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/gsamaras/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/code/}default-04a409/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] Total time: 25 s, completed Feb 10, 2016 5:11:30 PM
```

The Scala version, but I read somewhere it's irrelevant:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/code$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.6 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

and sbt version:

```
gsamaras@gsamaras:~/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/code$ sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to Simple Project (in build file:/home/gsamaras/spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6/code/)
[info] 0.11.3
```

---

Relevant: [SBT, Jetty and Servlet 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889674/sbt-jetty-and-servlet-3-0)

Comment: check the version? `1.0.2`??

Comment: How to do that @karthikmanchala please?

Comment: i mean in your simple.sbt file `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2"`

Comment: I do not understand @karthikmanchala. You want me to check the version of what? I am really new in Scala..and Java.

Comment: in the question.. i see the line `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2"`.. in this, version of spark you are using is defined as `1.0.2`.. right?  and i dont think thats what you want.. change it to 1.6.0 (the latest version)

Comment: I had tried that @karthikmanchala. I tried again and updated my post...

Comment: I just read https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/499. Could you maybe update to a more recent version of Sbt? 0.11 is really old ....Or you add the support for orbit (as described in the link)

Comment: OK I uninstalled sbt, by `sudo apt-get remove sbt`. How to install it to latest version in Ubuntu 14.04? http://askubuntu.com/questions/732092/how-to-install-sbt-in-its-latest-version-in-ubuntu-14-04 I did installed it like this the previous time: https://gist.github.com/bigsnarfdude/b2eb1cabfdaf7e62a8fc

Comment: Could you maybe run sudo apt-get update (and upgrade?)? because it seems that the repository contains 0.13, not 0.11 ...

Comment: I removed `sbt` now. How to upgrade @Markon? `sudo apt-get upgrade sbt`?

Comment: I did that and the version is still `0.11.3`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9889674/sbt-jetty-and-servlet-3-0

Comment: The upgrade **was the solution**.  @karthikmanchala or Markon feel free to post an answer! Link to this if you like http://askubuntu.com/questions/732092/how-to-install-sbt-in-its-latest-version-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update *sbt* to latest version, by doing (some steps might be optional):

```
sudo apt-get remove sbt
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
sudo apt-get upgrade sbt
```

and you will be fine.